# Python: Create a multidimensional array by stacking a 1D array in a loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Its been 2 days since I have been working on this problem but cannot break through. In the below code the inside for loop creates `pathwiseminS` an array of (252,) everytime it runs.

What I want is when this loop ends to stack this in another array (row by row or column by column, anything that works!). In the end creating a multidimensional array called `total` which should be either (200,252) or (252,200).

I have tried `np.concatenate`, '`np.vstack`, etc. but cannot get this right.

```
class pricing_lookback:
def __init__(self, spot, rate, sigma, time, sims, steps):
    self.spot = spot
    self.rate = rate
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.time = time
    self.sims = sims
    self.steps = steps
    self.dt = self.time / self.steps

def call_floatingstrike(self):

    simulationS = np.array([])
    simulationSt = np.array([])
    call2 = np.array([])
    total = np.array([])
    # total = np.empty(shape=[self.steps, self.sims])
    # total = np.empty(shape=self.steps,).reshape(self.steps)
    for j in range(self.sims):
        sT = self.spot
        pathwiseminS = np.array([])
        for i in range(self.steps):
            phi = np.random.normal()
            sT *= np.exp(
                (self.rate - 0.5 * self.sigma * self.sigma) * self.dt + self.sigma * phi * np.sqrt(self.dt))
            pathwiseminS = np.append(pathwiseminS, sT)
            total = pathwiseminS.copy()

        # print(np.shape(pathwiseminS))
        total = np.append([total],[total], axis=0)
        # np.hstack((total,pathwiseminS.transpose()))
        # print(np.size(b), np.shape(b))
        call2 = np.append(call2, max(pathwiseminS[self.steps - 1] - self.spot, 0))
        # print (pathwiseminS[self.steps-1])
        # print(call2)
        simulationSt = np.append(simulationSt, pathwiseminS[self.steps - 1])
        simulationS = np.append(simulationS, min(pathwiseminS))
    # print(b)
    call = max(np.average(simulationSt) - np.average(simulationS), 0)
    return call, total  # ,call2,
```

If I print `total` in the end I get `(2,252)` matrix

Comment: Why did you use `np.append` instead of list append? That's faster and easier to use.

Comment: Because I did not know about list append. I always thought that numpy arrays are faster

Comment: Iteration over lists is faster, especially when building new lists or arrays.  List append just adds a pointer to the list; it operates in-place.  `np.append` is a cover function for `np.concatenate`, and creates a new array each time (with full copy).  To get the iterative concatenate right you have to pay close attention to dimensions.  `np.array([])` has shape `(0,)`.  That can only concatenate with another 1d array.

Comment: `np.empty(shape=[self.steps, self.sims])` is a `(self.steps, self.sims)` shaped array containing unspecified values.  It is not equivalent to an `empty` list, `[]`.  You can concatenate it with another 2d array, with a shared dimension, but the result still has those unspecified values.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine solved it: basically reshaped the array on return. Also below is a free code to price a Floating Lookback Call Option.

```
class pricing_lookback:
def __init__(self, spot, rate, sigma, time, sims, steps):
    self.spot = spot
    self.rate = rate
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.time = time
    self.sims = sims
    self.steps = steps
    self.dt = self.time / self.steps

def call_floatingstrike(self):

    simulationS = np.array([])
    simulationSt = np.array([])
    call2 = np.array([])
    total = np.array([])
    for j in range(self.sims):
        sT = self.spot
        pathwiseminS = np.array([])
        for i in range(self.steps):
            phi = np.random.normal()
            sT *= np.exp(
                (self.rate - 0.5 * self.sigma * self.sigma) * self.dt + self.sigma * phi * np.sqrt(self.dt))
            pathwiseminS = np.append(pathwiseminS, sT)

        total = np.concatenate((total, pathwiseminS), axis=0)#This is add everything to one row
        call2 = np.append(call2, max(pathwiseminS[self.steps - 1] - self.spot, 0))
        simulationSt = np.append(simulationSt, pathwiseminS[self.steps - 1])
        simulationS = np.append(simulationS, min(pathwiseminS))

    call = max(np.average(simulationSt) - np.average(simulationS), 0)
    return call, total.reshape(self.sims, self.steps)# This transforms it to expected matrix
```

Comment: `np.append` without an `axis` parameter, flattens all inputs.  So you are just building one long flat array.  It's a good idea to look at the code for functions like `np.append` to see what they really end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical way of building an array from lists of lists:

```
In [127]: alist = [] 
     ...: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     sublist = [] 
     ...:     for j in range(4): 
     ...:         sublist.append(i*10+j) 
     ...:     alist.append(sublist) 
     ...:                                                                            
In [128]: alist                                                                      
Out[128]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23]]
In [129]: np.array(alist)                                                            
Out[129]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

I tried to replicate the list append approach with `concatenates`, but kept hitting errors like

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

In [130]: arr = np.zeros((0,4), int) 
     ...: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     arr1 = np.zeros((0),int) 
     ...:     for j in range(4): 
     ...:         arr1 = np.concatenate((arr1, np.array([i*10+j]))) 
     ...:     arr = np.concatenate((arr, arr1), axis=0)
```

I could eventually get dimensions right, but it isn't worth my time.

The fastest, non iterative approach is something like:

```
In [133]: np.arange(4)+10*np.arange(3)[:,None]                                       
Out[133]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

If you must iterate, it is easier to create a blank array of the right size, and assign values:

```
In [135]: arr = np.zeros((3,4),int) 
     ...: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     for j in range(4): 
     ...:         arr[i,j] = 10*i+j 
     ...: arr                                                                        
Out[135]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

This last approach has comparable speed to the list append one.

---

Cleaned up `concatenate` version.

`arr` will be 2d, (n,4), at each step.

`arr1` is 1d, (m,), at each step; it has to be expanded to 2d to concatenate with `arr`.

```
In [158]: arr = np.zeros((0,4), int) 
     ...: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     arr1 = np.zeros((0,),int) 
     ...:     for j in range(4): 
     ...:         arr1 = np.concatenate((arr1, np.array([i*10+j]))) 
     ...:     arr = np.concatenate((arr, arr1[None,:]), axis=0) 
     ...:                                                                            
In [159]: arr                                                                        
Out[159]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

`np.append` is just `concatenate` that makes sure the inputs are atleast 1d.  So we can use it in the inner loop.  `np.vstack` makes sure its inputs are 2d, so we can use it in the outer loop.  These just hide details; they don't change the speed.

```
In [161]: arr = np.zeros((0,4), int) 
     ...: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     arr1 = np.zeros((0,),int) 
     ...:     for j in range(4): 
     ...:         arr1 = np.append(arr1, i*10+j) 
     ...:     arr = np.vstack((arr, arr1))
```

Comment: if I do `total[i,j] = sT` would that work in the inner loop?